# How to set small notification icons in react-native according to device resolution

Tags: android, react-native

I'm receiving notifications and by now using default icons.
I want to customize them, but I really got lost in time to set the icon.

Using [react-native-firebase notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification).

I've already created right size icons with this online [notification icons generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit).

Then I created the directories in the places and with correct names, like following (Android):

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ (24x24)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ (36x36)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ (48x48)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ (72x72)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (96x96)
```

Now, I want to get the right sized image and resolve it here.

```
var notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
                  sound: 'default',
                  show_in_foreground: true,
             })
             .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
             .android.setChannelId("channel")
             .android.setSmallIcon(  <How do I put icon paths here?>  );
```

I've read some docs and guidelines, but I'm really not having an idea.
What is the right way to reference these paths?

Comment: path should be the name of the icon and make sure to put  the icon in mipmap folder

Comment: Thanks for answering. Asset Studio suggest me to create drawable folders. Should I put icons in drawable or mipmap? And then setSmallIcon("ic_custom_notif") is enough?

Comment: I got it when setting android.setSmallIcon("@mipmap/ic_custom_notif"). Thank you!

Comment: what about ios??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we suggest put the following line in your manifest, And then after put your all different size of the icon in mipmap folder, It will call as per resolution of the device.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_noti_icon" />
```

Comment: Thank you, its correct. I just had to declare android.setSmallIcon("@mipmap/ic_custom_notif") properly.

Comment: For me this meta-data-declaration works for incoming messages that come from the Firebase-servers. For local notifications the default icon still is just white.

Comment: For this you need to the created icon with a combination of transparent area and filled are because as per the latest change in status bar android show icon like the combination of transparent area icon.

Comment: what about ios??